# showDialog function is not passing parent context to its children in Flutter? is it conceived this way?

Tags: flutter, dart, builder, showdialog

Does builder function creates new context here, and how to pass context then.

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => Center(
  child: Container(
  child: Text('some text'),),));
```

result:

[image]

Comment: no, `builder` does not create the `context` - it simply uses the one provided by `context:` named parameter

Comment: showDialog function is called inside the onTap Function of GestureDetector widget inside my Scaffold

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Center` in `Dialog` widget to get a white background.

```
Dialog(
 child: Center(...)
)
```

If you want to keep it transparent, wrap the `Center` in `Material`

```
Material(
 child: Center(...)
)
```